# error: reached end of file while parsing } java Почему не работает?

Tags: java

Вот код:

```
 package GameDemo;
import GameDemo.GuessGame;
import GameDemo.Player;
    public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] args){
           Player p1 = new Player();
           p1.num = "PlayerOne";
           int guessp1 = 0;
           guessp1 = p1.guess();
           boolean variantp1 = false;

           Player p2 = new Player();
           p2.num = "PlayerTwo";
           int guessp2 = 0;
           guessp2 = p2.guess();
           boolean variantp2 = false;

           Player p3 = new Player();
           p3.num = "PlayerThree";
           int guessp3 = 0;
           guessp3 = p3.guess();
           boolean variantp3 = false;

           GuessGame Generator = new GuessGame();
           int generatornum = 0;
           generatornum = Generator.gener();

           while(true){
           System.out.println("Игра загадывает число...");

           System.out.println("Первый игрок думает, что это" + guessp1);
           System.out.println("Второй игрок думает, что это" + guessp2);
           System.out.println("Третий игрок думает, что это" + guessp3);

           System.out.println("Загаданное число - " + generatornum);

           if (guessp1 == generatornum){
               variantp1 = true;
           }
           if (guessp2 == generatornum){
               variantp2 = true;
           }
           if (guessp3 == generatornum){
               variantp3 = true;
           }
           if (variantp1 || variantp2 || variantp3){
               System.out.println("У нас есть победитель!");
               System.out.println("Первый игрок угадал?" + variantp1);
               System.out.println("Второй игрок угадал?" + variantp2);
               System.out.println("Третий игрок угадал?" + variantp3);
           } else{
               System.out.println("Попробуйте еще раз");
           }           
    }
}
```

Код двух импортируемых классов:

```
package GameDemo;
public class Player {
    String num;
    int mathrand = 0;

    public void rand(){
       mathrand = (int) (10*Math.random());  
    }
       public int guess(){
    System.out.print(mathrand);
    return mathrand;
   } 
}

package GameDemo;
public class GuessGame {
    int randomin = 0; 

    public void gennum(){
        randomin = (int) (10*Math.random());
    }
    public int gener(){
    System.out.println(randomin);
    return randomin;
    }
}
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Очевидно, что скобку потеряли где-то одну закрывающую `public class GameLauncher`

Comment: Netbeans такое замечает.

Comment: Замечает. И именно это Netbeans и говорит про ваш код.

Comment: Программа бы подсветила красным скобку без пары.

Comment: Нет. Пишет на последней скобке именно то, что у вас в заголовке. Если вы не верите уже как минимум трем человекам, то сосчитайте хотя бы скобки в своем коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас скобка класса `GameLauncher` не закрыта:

```
public class GameLauncher {
    ...
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Используйте единые отступы, например по 4 пробела, так чтобы сохранялась структура вложенности, например:

```
public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...

        while (true) {
            ...

            if (guessp1 == generatornum) {
                ...
            }
            ...
            if (variantp1 || variantp2 || variantp3) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Иначе, можете ошибиться.

Если кода слишком много (не влезает на экран), то оберните его в функции.

Comment: Если файл разросся, то можно произвести автоформатирование (в нетбинс Source - Format или Alt + Shift + F) и отступы расставятся автоматически.